# Navigation goes below elements - z-index not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have navigation bar which is placed below the header and when it gets to the top of the viewport it becomes sticky. I'm using `jquery.sticky` library to do that.

The problem is, when scrolling, other items on the webpage get on top of the navigation. Navigation remains black (as black is the color of it) but I can see text and images getting above it.

I've tried to use the following code on the elements below navigation in CSS:

```
position: relative;
z-index: -1;
```

That does the job and now the navigation is the top element, but I have a form on the bottom of the page and can't access input fields because of that.

Here's my code:

HTML

```
<section class="navigacija" id="sticky-nav">
    <nav>
        <ul>
           <div class="container">
              <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-md-4">
                    <li id="nav-about"><a href="#">about</a></li>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-md-4">
                    <li id="nav-devs"><a href="#">devs</a></li>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-md-4">
                    <li id="nav-joinus"><a href="#">join us</a></li>
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.navigacija {
    background-color: #000;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
}
```

JS:

```
$(window).load(function(){
      $("#sticky-nav").sticky({ topSpacing: 0 });
    });
```

Can anyone help me out?

ALL FILES -> https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2VRToUeRJBUTTRXc2t4THdnaUU

Comment: Could you add a fiddle with this code?

Comment: You need to make a working snippet ( with that library ) so we can replicate your problem. Maybe add `z-index:9999` to the sticky nav ? i cannot replicate that problem now

Comment: Add `position: relative; z-index: 999;` to .navigacija class and try..
if this not work the please add full code.

Comment: Does not work. I posted a link of the project, don't want to paste hundreds of lines of code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I your case you need to add hight z-index to *#sticky-nav-sticky-wrapper*. For example:

```
#sticky-nav-sticky-wrapper {  
  position: relative; 
  z-index: 999;
}
```

Or you can add **!important** to  *.navigacija* .For example:

```
.navigacija {
    background-color: #000;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 999!important;
}
```

You need it because jquery plugin adds its own styles with **style** attribute. And they have more priority

Comment: Thank you sir, you saved my day!

Comment: No problem, glad to help